# Invalid memory access fortran inspector

Tags: arrays, memory, fortran, inspector

I'm getting wrong calculated values if I run my fortran program with arrays (look at the code). If I use the intel inspector (-mi3) it will tell me that there are memory problems "invalid memory access" each time one of the big arrays is used in the program and also an error in  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2. 
First of all I thought I have not enough memory space but on my 64 bit machine with 16 GB memory there is enough memory space (:free -m ~14 GB).
If I estimate the memory size of my program, around 4 GB  should be enough. While my program is running the used memory is increasing from 0% to ~20 % and stops there until the program terminates "normally". So I think I have enough memory space. For small arrays (e.g. nemax=3 000 000) I obtain the right calculated values and no errors in the intel inspector. I also checked the arrays with flag check all.
I compile the program with ifort -mcmodel=medium -shared-intel -o test test.f90.
I don't what else I could do to solve these memory access errors? Has anyone an idea??
Thanks for your help!

```
  module lz_data

  integer,parameter :: maxsite=16   
  integer,parameter :: nmax =6000000 
  integer,parameter :: nemax=300000000

  real*8,save :: diag(nmax)        

  real*8,save  :: werte(nemax)              !Here are the only large arrays
  integer,save :: izeile(nemax)
  integer,save :: ispalt(nemax)

  integer,save :: nentry

  end module lz_data

  prgram test
  use lz_data

  implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
  real*8 umat(maxsite,maxsite)
  logical lav(nmax,maxsite) 
  logical lbv(nmax,maxsite) 

  ...

  do is=1,ns
    diag(is)=0.0d0    ! HERE the debugging tool says invalid memory access 
    do i=1,msite
      do j=1,msite
        if (lav(is,i).and.lbv(is,j)) diag(is)=diag(is)+umat(i,j) ! invalid memory access
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
```

Comment: You have explicitly used implicit typing.  You are then using undeclared and uninitialised variables such as `is`, `ns` and `msite` for controlling your loops.  It is no surprise to me that `diag(is)` references an invalid memory location if you haven't initialised `ns`.  And please don't tell me that you have omitted the declaration and initialisation of those variables, debugging other people's code is hard enough when I can see all of it, hiding essential lines is jolly bad sport.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but why are my variables undeclared. If I use implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z) all variables starting with i-n are integers.

Comment: Rather than split hairs over whether they are declared or not, tell us where and to what values they are initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running into some static array size limitations. mcmodel=medium "should" help with that, but apparently it doesn't. You could replace your big static arrays with allocatable arrays and see if that helps.

Oh, and like High Performane Mark said, use implicit none, make sure to initialize all variables, and provide a self-contained example code.

Comment: Thanks for your Help! I have already set ulimit -s unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other excellent advice, I suggest compiling with as many debugging options turned on as possible, including runtime error checking.  The compiler will give you warnings about bad practices that are likely to caused errors and will find other errors.  Bad practices include undeclared or uninitialized variables.  I suggest not using implicit typing and to declare every variable.  With runtime subscript checking, the compiler will tell you when a subscript goes outside of the bounds of an array ... a more understandable error than invalid memory access.  With intel ifort try: `-O2  -stand f03    -assume realloc_lhs  -check all  -traceback  -warn all  -fstack-protector  -assume protect_parens  -implicitnone`

After editing your code example so that it will compile cleanly with the rules enforced by these options, running gives the error message:

```
forrtl: severe (193): Run-Time Check Failure. The variable '_test_$NS' is being used without being defined
```

i.e., ifort finds an uninitalized variable at runtime.  Which was causing the program to run over the end of the array and access invalid memory.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the other advices, you should also make sure, you are not hit by the default stack size limit in your shell. Static arrays are usually created on the stack, and the default stack size in BASH is 8Mb. If you have arrays bigger than that you end up with access violation. You can override this limit by setting

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

in BASH, so that your stack size is only limited by the memory available in your system.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your help! I have already set ulimit -s unlimited or 10 GB. I know using implicit isn't so good, but for smaller systems my program runs absolutely fine so why should there be an error with using implicit. I would like to use allocatable arrays instead of the big static arrays, but in my case it doesn't make sense, because the calculation of the values of the large array werte is linked with the extent of the array. So I have to waste a little(!) of memory in predicting a sufficient  dimension for my static arrays. Predicting the dimension is in my case not  complicate and I'm absolutely (100%) sure that the calculated array fits in the static array. I even checked it with -check all flag. I can create an allocatable array with the diag(nmax) array so I will check this, but this array is by far not as large as the werte(nemax) array.

Comment: Using implicit typing is not necessarily wrong, but it makes code harder to follow and has a risk of producing tricky errors. Using `implicit none` provides large benefits at a (nowadays) very small cost, especially since you explicitly declare the types and kinds for most of your variables anyway. Also, what is your objection to allocatable arrays? They are convenient wherever you have array whose size needs to change or is not known until run time.